# PySimpleGUI - Alinhamento de Botão em colunas

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando um problema com o alinhamento de 2 colunas, o que ocorre é que a segunda coluna possui um botão e eu gostaria de deixa-lo alinhado a direita (como na segunda imagem) permanecendo com o conteúdo da primeira coluna alinhado a esquerda (como na primeira imagem).

Já tentei utilizar o `Column(element_justification='right')` mas não funcionou, entretanto se eu utilizo o `Column(justification='right')` tudo vai pra direita, inclusive a coluna anterior. Tentei outras coisas mas nada deu certo.

Atualmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando  o `Column(justification='right')`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from webbrowser import open
gitLink = 'https://github.com/DiegoAL'
sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')
# Elementos da janela

cbox_layout = [[sg.Checkbox('Iniciar o Profitchart após limpeza', True, enable_events=True, key='start')],
               [sg.Checkbox('Fechar após limpeza', enable_events=True, key='close')],
               [sg.Checkbox('Escolher um executável especifico', enable_events=True, key='newPath')]]

btn_layout = [[sg.Button('Limpar!', size=(10, 4), enable_events=True, key='clear')]]

layout = [[sg.Column(cbox_layout),
          sg.Column(btn_layout)],
          [sg.In(), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('Idealizado por: Diego Alves'),
           sg.Text('Link do Projeto', size=(24, 0),
           justification='right', enable_events=True, key='link',
           text_color='blue', font='underline')]] #[FIX] font não esta funcionando
# Criacao e demais configuracoes da janela
window = sg.Window('Profitchart Cleaner', layout)

# Leitura dos dados e eventos
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # Fechar aplicacao
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    # Acessar a pagina do Projeto
    if event == 'link':
        open(gitLink)

window.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma alternativa que encontrei para resolver seu problema de alinhamento é adicionar uma coluna vazia entre as caixas de seleções e o botão e ajustar o tamanho com `size=`:

```
layout = [[sg.Column(cbox_layout),
           sg.Column([[sg.Text('',size=(2,0))]]),
           sg.Column(btn_layout)],
```

Aqui utilizei `size=(2, 0)` e ficou bem ajustado à lateral direita, resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu código completo:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from webbrowser import open
gitLink = 'https://github.com/DiegoAL'
sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')
# Elementos da janela

cbox_layout = [[sg.Checkbox('Iniciar o Profitchart após limpeza', True, enable_events=True, key='start')],
               [sg.Checkbox('Fechar após limpeza', enable_events=True, key='close')],
               [sg.Checkbox('Escolher um executável especifico', enable_events=True, key='newPath')]]

btn_layout = [[sg.Button('Limpar!', size=(10, 4), enable_events=True, key='clear')]]

layout = [[sg.Column(cbox_layout),
           sg.Column([[sg.Text('',size=(2,0))]]),
          sg.Column(btn_layout)],
          [sg.In(), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('Idealizado por: Diego Alves'),
           sg.Text('Link do Projeto', size=(24, 0),
           justification='right', enable_events=True, key='link',
           text_color='blue', font='underline')]] #[FIX] font não esta funcionando
# Criacao e demais configuracoes da janela
window = sg.Window('Profitchart Cleaner', layout)

# Leitura dos dados e eventos
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # Fechar aplicacao
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    # Acessar a pagina do Projeto
    if event == 'link':
        open(gitLink)

window.close()
```